# How to resolve "Established libraries must be included separately" comment on Firefox Add On review?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, handlebars.js, libraries, firefox-addon-webextensions

One of my Firefox add on failed review and I got the following comment:

> Established libraries must be included separately, from their official source, in their original format without any modification (changing the file name does not matter). Please note that only stable releases of are acceptable (not beta, pre, RC, dev etc). Minified versions are better. Please note that third party CDNs are not considered official sources for this purpose.
>
> There is no need to include .map files for established libraries.
>
> Eg: js/handlebars.min.js

Note: *I'm using stable & minified handlerbar.js downloaded from their site itself without any modification. I don't have any .map files in my project also.*

Any idea what does this comment means and how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Could it be a case of accidental line endings change as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799095/mozilla-add-ons-rejecting-jquery-despite-not-being-modified ?

Comment: Run some hashing (e.g. `md5sum`) on freshly-downloaded copy and the one in your final build to see if they differ.